# rsyslog "if" statement doesn't work

Tags: linux, rsyslog

I have the following statement in my `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
# This one is the template to generate the log filename dynamically
$template DynFile,"/var/log/proxy/%$year%/%$month%/%$now%.log"

if $fromhost-ip == '192.168.1.1' then *.* ?DynFile
```

The idea is to split a local and remote logs into separate dirs and files.

rsyslog daemon starts without any errors but expected logs are not created. If I replace "if" statement with simple `*.* ?DynFile` then logs are populated, but of course then they aren't splitted.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, i think it's just a syntax error :

```
$template DynFile,"/var/log/proxy/%$year%/%$month%/%$now%.log"
if $fromhost-ip == '127.0.0.1' then ?DynFile
```

** I use "127.0.0.1" for localhost